# iOS multiple fetchCompletionHandler for remote notifications

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I'm making an instant messenger in iOS and I have difficulties to understand how background remote notifications exactly work. I'm using XMPP to manage message transfers which translates in TCP persistent connection. Then I have the following scenario:

- I send the app in background closing the connection
- a push notification arrives because of a new message, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is called, then I re-establish the connection to download the message and upload the receipt that the message has been received; finally I disconnect TCP (remaining in background)
- before I call the `completionHandler` passing the appropriate `UIBackgroundFetchResult`, another remote notification arrives causing the same behavior of previous point

at this point I have two `completionHandler`s to call.

My questions is: what actually happens when I call the first `completionHandler`? Does the connection disconnect or it doesn't disconnect until the second one is called?